# Pecl / Python: unsupported locale setting - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, locale, pecl

I want to install pecl ssh2 extension. But when i try:

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.3.2 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I'v tried everything, yes everything that i found on google!

What i'v tried:

1- On the terminal

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

2- Editing environment (/etc/environment)

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

3- Editing locale (/etc/default/locale)

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

4- apt-get update & upgrade

5- Rebooting system

locale command:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Locale does not support LC_ALL as you had seen in the message "locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory". Unset LC_ALL, you may be able to escape from the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give following command :

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base -y && sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This should fix your problem.